# Question about variance explained and group differences

Tags: variance, group-differences, genetics

A heritability statistic, as I understand it, describes the percent of variation in a trait that is attributable to genetic variation, with the rest attributable to environmental variation.

I've heard it described that if you have a heritability estimate for a trait of 50% and two groups' means differ in that trait by 1 standard deviation, that means for environment to explain all of the difference, the groups' mean environments must differ by 1.5 standard deviations. Is that accurate? Because I'm having a hard time grasping how that necessarily follows based on my lay understanding of heritability.